# Magento 2 Custom Controller get MetaTitle

Tags: controllers, magento-2.1

In my controller I have the following code but I want to display also the meta title of the product in the browser. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

```
class Product extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $pageFactory;
public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $page_object = $this->pageFactory->create();
    return $page_object;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following way

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
// set title
$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set('Something');

// get title
echo $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->get();

// get meta information
print_r($resultPage->getConfig()->getMetadata());
```

Check available method into following class

```
Magento/Framework/View/Page/Config.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need the meta title to be displayed not the page title. any idea?

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately I cant figure it :-(